# How to fix 'Error: No .desktop files found' for manual AppImage creation

Tags: linux, x86-64, appimage

I am following the manual packaging guide on the AppImage GitHub manual. For AppRun I am using the AppRun-x86_64 from https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/releases (7th July 2019)
I have a name.desktop file in a name.AppImage folder where I replaced name with the project name and the name.desktop gives no error if validated by `desktop-file-validate`.
Yet, I receive the following error message when running the created AppImage and when running `./AppRun` directly:

`Error: No .desktop files found`

Where does it look for the file and what is the required naming scheme?

Version of appimagetool `appimagetool, continuous build (commit fef038a), build 2093 built on 2019-07-07 12:07:34 UTC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Accidentally copied the `AppRun` to my executable. So `AppRun` -> calls `AppRun` can't find the `.desktop` in the `usr/bin` directory.
I leave the question in case somebody makes the same mistake.